# Change property of class in wkwebview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebview in my IOS Application.

I'm using:

```
bookingView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('nearbyLink').style = 'display:none';") { (response, err) in
            if let err = err{
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

to remove a specific element by it's ID (This works fine!), but somehow this does not work on all elements.

I'm trying to remove another element by its class name using `document.getElementsByClassName()` but it's still not being removed.

I've tried to remove the elements using this
[how to hide html elements in wkwebview in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822699/how-to-hide-html-elements-in-wkwebview-in-ios)
but still doesn't work.

Is there any other way I can remove objects in WKWebview?

So let's say I wanna remove a link like:

```
<form class="sort-options">
```

How can I change the code and add like this:

```
 <form class="sort-options" style="display:none">
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**The webpage is not owned by me!**